# How to check how many instances created for a type in c#?

Tags: c#, oop

How can I check that number of instances created for a particular type and how much memory each instance occupied. Please give an example.

Comment: Programmatically?

Comment: Is this a class you have created?

Comment: The best way to count the number of instance of any class is to keep a `static` `int` counter in your class and increment it by 1 in the constructor and decrement by one in dispose method. Make sure thatIDisposable interface is implemented

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment i will add an example

```
public class Myclass
{
    private static long Count;

    public Myclass()
    {
         Interlocked.Increment(ref Count);
    }
}
```

This will only work for your own class, In this way you can't find out the number of instances of `System.String` for example.

To find out the size of a class, You should use this `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyField;
    public int MyField;
}
```

And:

```
 int sizeInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyClass)); //return 8
```

[Also you have here a list with size of int, byte, etc.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Moshe I tried it this helps me !!